# json editor, how to delete tab and add label/entry inside the tab tkinter

Tags: python, json, tkinter

I have this program that made tab i would like to made labels and entry for each tab
using a for loop or something?

```
from tkinter import *
import json
from tkinter.filedialog import asksaveasfile
import time
from tkinter import ttk
import math
import sys

root = Tk()
root.geometry('1000x1200')
root.title('Json Editor')
root.counter = 0
root.uncounter = -1
tabcontrol=ttk.Notebook(root, width=800, height=800)

NewWorkLab=Label(root,text="Name: ")
NewWorkLab.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky="W")

NewWorkEntry=Entry(root)
NewWorkEntry.grid(row=0,column=1,sticky="W")



def AddNewWork():
    root.counter +=1
    print(root.counter)
    TabName=ttk.Frame(tabcontrol)
    tabcontrol.add(TabName,text=NewWorkEntry.get())

    TabName.ttk.Label(TabName,  text ="Welcomes").grid(column = 0,  
                               row = 0, 
                               padx = 30, 
                               pady = 30)  
    TabName.tabcontrol.ttk.Entry(TabName,  text ="this label is wrong").grid(column = 1, 
                                    row = 0,  
                                    padx = 30, 
                                    pady = 30) 



def deletetab():
    tabcontrol.forget(tabcontrol.select())
 #   tabcontrol.destroy(TabName, root.counter)



AddWorkButton=Button(root,text=' Add ', command=AddNewWork)
AddWorkButton.grid(row=0,column=2, sticky="W")


RemWorkTab=Button(root,text=' Rem ', command=deletetab)
RemWorkTab.grid(row=0,column=3, sticky="W")
tabcontrol.grid(row=1,column=0,columnspan=2,padx=5)

root.mainloop()
```

finally my question

- how can i make appear stuff like labels and entry inside the tabs that i created with the second program?

would be great having help thanks

Comment: somebody answered and deleted the answer it was a good answer, i can't get it back

Comment: You've posted far too much code. Please try to focus on a single problem, and post the absolute minimum amount of code to illustrate the problem you're having. For example, we don't need 17 input widgets if you're struggling with how to get data out of one. If you're struggling with dynamically creating tabs, those tabs don't need 17 entry widgets, and so on.

Comment: i put two point i would like to have focus on the 2nd point cause would answer also the first(because of code repetition), even tho i have to rewrite everything

Comment: Please try to rewrite question and create a new [mcve] for the purposes of the question.

Comment: modified and made it simple--- how can i mark the tab created and give a tab a sort of mark to after being able to delete it?

Comment: What does the first paragraph mean? What is the "second code"?

Answer (score 0):

> how can i make appear stuff like labels and entry inside the tabs that i created with the second program?

You need to store a reference to the tab in a list or dictionary. You can then add widgets into a tab using the list index. For example, to add a label to tab `i`, you would do something like this:

```
tablist = []
def AddNewWork():
    tab=ttk.Frame(tasktabs)
    tasktabs.add(tab,text=NewWorkEntry.get())
    tablist.append(tab)
...
i =   # whatever tab number you want to modify
tab = tablist[i]
tab.button = Button(tab, text="Click me!")
tab.label = Label(tab, text="I'm a label")
```

> How can i delete the tab that i created with the button?? Without having a fixed numbers of tabs as in the third program??

The same technique applies: call the `destroy` method on an element in the list. You should also remove the item from the list. For example, assuming you want to delete tab `i`, you would do something like this:

```
i =   # whatever tab number you want to modify
tab = tablist.pop(i)
tab.destroy()
```

Comment: How now can i make a label inside my tab??

Comment: @ayucaba: the exact same way I showed how to create a button.

Comment: an error saying    tablist = [i]
NameError: name 'i' is not defined

Comment: @ayucaba: well, yes. You have to tell it which one you want to add items to.

Comment: plese make a better example